# turn a ul li list to multiple selection fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, listview, drop-down-menu

For a while I'm searching for a solution to make multi listboxes or dropdown boxes. I don't know if it is possible, but I want to convert a generated ul li list with several levels to a mulit selectbox. Can anybody help me out?

I generate a ul li by this function:

```
{function displayCategories level=0 start=0 limit=null}

{if $level==0}<div class="catergie">{/if}
<ul class="nav{if $level==0}1{/if}">

    {foreach $category.categories as $subcategory}
        {if $subcategory@index < $start}{continue}{/if}

        {if empty($subcategory.categories)}
            <li>
                <a href="?listing_package_sid={$listing_package_sid}&amp;category_id={$subcategory.id}#listing-add-form-two">
                   <span class="nav-tabs">[[$subcategory.caption]]</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        {else}
            <li class="hasChild">
                <span class="nav-tabs notHover">[[$subcategory.caption]]</span>
                {displayCategories category=$subcategory level=$level+1}
            </li>
        {/if}
        {if !is_null($limit) && $limit + $start == $subcategory@iteration}</div>{break}{/if}
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```

{/function}

I want to put the generated list to a DropDownList of a Listbox.

See jsfiddle:

[on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/postie/bahd3qcg/](https://jsfiddle.net/postie/bahd3qcg/)

Thanks!

Comment: instead of trying it like this you can make use of bootstrap-multi-selct-dropdown.. https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect check it..

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a jQuery library and the Menu plugin (https://jqueryui.com/menu/). Then converting is as simple as

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".nav1" ).menu();
  });
  </script>
```

And you'd better use an id to address the top ul instead of a class name.